# What if command (ethtool) to flash physical ports on NIC does not work? How can I identify which of the live ports are flapping?

Tags: ethtool

I have 2 live ports and one of which has network flapping issue. ethtool -p  runs but does not flash my ports. What else can I do without pulling the wrong fiber?

Comment: read the label on the cable, I mean, you did label all your cabling, yes?

Comment: The standard label given there just makes the cable unique for tracing physically from switch to server. Any other workarounds?

Comment: ID the servers via the labels. OS will have flapping interfaces logged in syslog.

Comment: Yes I have the logs and the interface names already, thing is both are still live observed physically. How do I be sure I’m pulling the flapping port if the ethtool command doesnt work for my server. Basically looking for an alternative for ethtool -p

Comment: `ethtool -p` requires the driver to be able to control the LEDs, and not all drivers include them. probably try your NIC-specific driver or executable to do that.

Comment: Hmm meaning to say without that there is no other way?